# How secure is the traffic behind and AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

AWS ELB load balancers can be configure to decrypt HTTPS traffic and then pass it through application servers on the network.

If this were inside my company network, it would leave the traffic wide open to IP sniffing from within our network. Is the same true in AWS?

Comment: A little background on how AWS built the VPC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd5hsL-JNY4

Answer (score 3):

It's probably more precise to say an ELB can terminate HTTPS so long as it has the appropriate certificate / key, rather than decrypt it. Decrypt which implies something unauthorised. Terminating https on the load balancer is quite common.

[Packet Sniffing](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/vpc-security-capabilities/) (aka promiscuous mode) is not possible in AWS. Traffic is effectively point to point. Your traffic is safe on the AWS network whether it's http or https.

You might like to read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38685/aws-vpc-should-connections-between-instances-be-over-ssl) as well.

Answer (score 1):

An AWS engineer or someone with wire-level access to the datacenter could sniff then network. AWS will say this list is very small and well regulated. If your content needs to be protected to that level then having your devices speak TLS all the way through is warranted. Otherwise it is probably fine to terminate SSL at the load-balancer and speak cleartext from there.

Other customers cannot sniff. All the usual games of arp-spoofing etc do not work.